# S3 storage without versionning get cached images

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-s3, storage

I get a strange problem with my s3 storage.
I develop a web-application which need image storage.
On the application, we need to make many update on them and display them in live so we disabled version management on the bucket.

we store the different url in a postgres DB and display them on the website.
But sometimes (can't really know in which condition because it seems to be random) the app display the old version of the image.

I try set some things in the metadata of my update request but it doesn't seems to do anythings.
Also we tried to add a ?versionId=null params at the end of the url but also we keep having issues

Did someone have an idea on this ?

Comment: It sounds like the content is being cached in the web browser. (You can test this by trying the page in another browser.) If so, you might be able to set metadata to make the objects expire more quickly in the browser, something like: [aws s3 add expire / cache header to existing objects](https://gist.github.com/stefan-mees/5803315)

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for your answer.

The strange things is that even with cach reload/private nav/other nav. The time wich we have the new format seems to be random.

After some research it seems to be our internet provider that make sheet on caching things on some different tings (DNS for exemple are totally random for some provider)

For the moment it seems to be fixed.
We're waiting for client review